# What is the time complexity of this algorithm? It is a bit tricky

Tags: algorithm, asymptotic-complexity

Suppose we have triple for loop, however, the O(1) statements within them are independent of the first loop so this for instance:

```
for (int i=1; i<=n; i++)
{
   for ( int j=1; j<=20; j++)
   {
       for (int k=1; k<=5; k++)
               {
                     //some statements independent of n 
               }
    }
}
```

Since the statements are independent of n in the most inner for loop, wouldn't it just be O(n^2) as opposed to O(n^3)? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please, notice that inner loops *don't depend* on `n`:

```
for ( int j=1; j<=20; j++) 
   {
       for (int k=1; k<=5; k++)
               {
                     //some statements independent of n 
               }
    }
```

that's why you can rewrite the the initial problem into

```
for (int i=1; i<=n; i++) {
   //some statements independent of n 
}
```

and you have `O(n)` complexity

Answer (score 2):

It's O(n) with probably a larger constant. The two inner loops are fixed and independent of n.

Answer (score 1):

It's O(n). Only one loop depends on n. Think about setting n to a very very high number. Than the others loop aren't really interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Basically the total number of iterations that your code runs through is = N*20*5, which is basically equal to running N iterations, therefore your time complexity is O(N).